# Can I use an accelerometer to measure the velocity of a car in a curve?

Tags: accelerometer, gyroscope

I am making an application that is used to measure the velocity, it has an accelerometer that measures the component acceleration in the XYZ-axis. When the car is moving just straight the measurement is ok, as only linear components are involved.

My doubt came when the car is on a curve, I am not sure if the accelerometer can measure correctly in such situation or if it is necessary to apply a gyroscope to measure any missing component.

The code snippet for measure the total acceleration is shown below, I measure the acceleration in each axis and I remove the gravitational to finally calculate the velocity and the speed

```
    float AccTotal_X = ((AcX - grav_X)*9.81);
    float AccTotal_Y = ((AcY - grav_Y)*9.81);
    float AccTotal_Z = ((AcZ - grav_Z)*9.81);

    float Vx = vx_0 + AccTotal_X*dt;
    vx_0 = Vx;
    float Vy = vy_0 + AccTotal_Y*dt;
    vy_0 = Vy;
    float Vz = vz_0 + AccTotal_Z*dt;
    vz_0 = Vz;

    speed_dt = sqrt(pow(Vx,2)+pow(Vy,2)+pow(Vz,2))*3.6;
```

Comment: What hardware are you using? Most accelerometers also include turn sensors. But there's a great range in quality of these things, from very inaccurate for $5 to highly accurate for $60000.

Comment: Note that the gravity only acts in one direction. You don't need to multiply with the gravity in all axes.

Comment: @PMF, I am using the MPU5060, it has both accelerometer and gyroscope, however, I am justing using the accelerometer to measure the acceleration linear to get the velocity.

Comment: @PMF about the gravity being multiplied in all axis is because depending on the inclination of the sensor on the plane, the gravity will be present in one or more axis

Comment: @GustavoDaSilvaGhedim Are you getting accurate results? Accelerometers usually have bias and noise which usually make them unsuitable to compute velocity by integrating their readings.

Comment: @Sacha for straight moviments the results have good accuracy, however, the problem comes when the vehicle is turning left or right, during such a situation the difference between reading and the true velocity is considerable

Comment: That's sure right. But you have to know which direction is down. Typically, that is obtained when the device is in a standstill.

Comment: You're probably better off on the physics (or maybe maths) stack, since you're getting into the realms of integrating angular acceleration and other complex topics that are far outside the realms of this stack.

Comment: I think the last line of the Wikipedia page on angular acceleration sums it up nicely: **"In conclusion, the general relation between torque and angular acceleration is necessarily more complicated than that for force and linear acceleration"**

Comment: Yes, you need the gyroscope. You can't determine the radius of the curve with the accelerometer only, but that is critical.

Comment: @SimSon, thank you for the answer, but do you know how could I represent it in the equation or which source could I find it, most sources that I read the just represent the linear case, there was none explaining about the the linear and circular in the same case

Comment: As long as the car does not slip or drift, the rotation angle of the car (gyroscope) equals the angel it passes around the curve's center. The same applies to angular velocity and acceleration. The equation is centripetal vs momentum: m*a=m*v^2/r or a=w^2*r

Answer (score 2):

I found out the answer to the question in the following article [**SenSpeed: Sensing Driving Conditions to Estimate Vehicle Speed in Urban Environments**](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6847999)

According to the article

> When a vehicle makes a turn, it experiences a centripetal force, which
> is related to its speed, angular speed and turning radius. Thus, by
> utilizing the accelerometer and the gyroscope, we can derive the
> tangential speed of a vehicle.

Therefore, just with the accelerometer is not possible to measure the velocity when an object is making a turn, it is necessary a gyroscope also.

The equation to measure the tangential velocity is:

**v = Rω** (1),

Where **v** is the tangential speed, **R** the radius of the curve and **ω** the angular speed.

As the centripetal acceleration is given by **a = ω²R** (2), reformulating (2) and substituting in (1), it is obtained:

**v = a/ω** (3).

Both **a** and **ω** are given by the accelerometer and the gyroscope respectively.